# Integral representation for the operator $\frac{\log{\Delta}}{\Delta}$ in two dimensions

Tags: laplacian, greens-function, differential-operators, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Recently, I have stumbled upon the following non-local operator in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
$$
\frac{\log{\Delta}}{\Delta} \ ,
$$
where $\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}$ represents the Laplacian operator. According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03416.pdf , the logarithm of the Laplacian operator should be defined as
$$
\left. \log\Delta=\frac{d}{ds}\Delta^s \right\rvert_{s=0} \ .
$$

I read https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03416.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf and I am now aware of the integral representations in two dimensions of the inverse Laplacian $\Delta^{-1}$ (up to my understanding, this corresponds to the Laplacian's Green's function), of the fractional Laplacian $\Delta^s$ and of the Logarithmic Laplacian $\log \Delta$.

I am very new to this whole subject, so I would like to ask

1. if an integral representation of the non-local operator $\frac{\log{\Delta}}{\Delta}$ is known in two dimensions;
2. for any references that could allow me to understand how to derive such an integral representation.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for where you encountered the operator $\frac{\log \Delta}{\Delta}$? I'm asking because I've seen all the others, but not that one.

Comment: I have encountered that operator at the end of a computation of mine (the evaluation of a 2d effective action at 1-loop). I have been looking for references but I couldn't find them unfortunately.